# Security Cross-cutting Concern

Tags: c#, data-layers

I appreciate that Security is seen as a cross-cutting concern and in my current development I have built my security as a seperate component that can be used by my various layers. Within my security component there is a data access layer used to retrieve users, groups etc.

However, having this data layer with the security component just doesn't seem right to me when its used within an application which again has its own data layer.

Have I got this wrong?

Comment: It depends... Is this an SOA architecture that requires its own security component? Stand alone app? Something else? Also, in terms of the data layer of the application - is it something that _can_ be used by the security component?

Comment: Yes, its a SOA architecture. I'm using wcf services over my business layer / data layer with the security component performing authorisation checks on each call (caching user security context though for future calls). My security component does not use the data layer of the application at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there is nothing wrong with this approach. If you want to keep security secure and free of potential issues introduced by changes to common DAL, keep it separate. Plus if security tables are used only by security component and there is not much common business logic, it does not give you much to have it in a common DAL. It would probably make it a bit safer - separate data connection for security checks.